# Rename the [bfr] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We've have the enigmatic [spacex](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacex) project that was tentatively called the BFR, or Big F[alcon] Rocket. Elon Musk likes to shoot from the hip and the F means something else. Unsurprisingly, they didn't want to issue press releases with that word, so the project has now officially been given a name:

Starship

It's not technically accurate (this isn't going to go to another star system) but that's its name. Musk [calls it that now](https://www.popularmechanics.com/space/rockets/a25953663/elon-musk-spacex-bfr-stainless-steel/). So BFR is no longer correct.

I would suggest we rename the tag to [spacex-starship](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacex-starship) (since [starship] may prove to be too generic in the future) and make [bfr] a synonym

Comment: I proposed this in November: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9682?m=47692494#47692494. Note that Elon Musk's explanation of the terminology may require us to split the tag. See the article I linked a few comments up from the permalinked chat comment.

Comment: I finished the retagging. I did not map bfr as a synonym to either tag, as I think that would be confusing. We should probably add something to the tag excerpt of spacex-starship and spacex-super-heavy about bfr.

Comment: @called2voyage I would suggest you make [bfr] a synonym of [spacex-starship] (the booster is unlikely to become as famous as the spacecraft). That would help people tag and avoid recreation

Comment: I'm not comfortable with doing that unilaterally. I suggest making a new meta post for that suggestion and/or submitting a tag synonym suggestion yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the names have become official, as they are referenced on the [SpaceX website](https://www.spacex.com/mars):

> This first private lunar passenger flight, featuring a fly-by of the Moon as part of a weeklong mission, will help fund development of SpaceX's **Starship** and **Super Heavy** (formerly known as BFR), an important step in enabling access for everyday people who dream of flying to space.

<sup>emphasis added</sup>

That said, I propose two tags: [spacex-starship](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacex-starship) for the upper stage and [spacex-super-heavy](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacex-super-heavy) for the launcher.

Comment: We need a retag campaign for all [bfr questions](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bfr). Also, we need to decide whether bfr will be a synonym of super heavy, starship, or neither.

Comment: Retagging complete.

Answer (score 2):

To aid in the retag campaign, I have put suggested tagging below. I would prefer if people look over this list and make sure everything is correct prior to retagging.

[spacex-starship](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacex-starship):

- [Why can't SpaceX Starship perform the same landing procedure as the Falcon 9 does?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33078/why-cant-spacex-starship-perform-the-same-landing-procedure-as-the-falcon-9-doe)
- [What are SpaceX Starship/BFR proposed abort modes?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33837/what-are-spacex-starship-bfr-proposed-abort-modes)
- [How will SpaceX Starship deploy its payload?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33739/how-will-spacex-starship-deploy-its-payload)
- [Active liquid cooling for heat shield](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33692/active-liquid-cooling-for-heat-shield)
- [Why has SpaceX changed Starship from carbon fiber composite to stainless steel?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33155/why-has-spacex-changed-starship-from-carbon-fiber-composite-to-stainless-steel)
- [How does SpaceX plan to deal with boiloff on the trip to Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30950/how-does-spacex-plan-to-deal-with-boiloff-on-the-trip-to-mars)
- [Details about the BFR abort procedures?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32087/details-about-the-bfr-abort-procedures)
- [Will it be possible to see BFR approaching the moon from earth, with naked eye?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32064/will-it-be-possible-to-see-bfr-approaching-the-moon-from-earth-with-naked-eye)
- [Drawbacks and advantages of two slidable & rotatable control surfaces for BFS sized spaceships](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31528/drawbacks-and-advantages-of-two-slidable-rotatable-control-surfaces-for-bfs-si)
- [BFR ticket cost](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27495/bfr-ticket-cost)
- [How will they mitigate the effect microgravity has in the BFR on manned trip to mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25758/how-will-they-mitigate-the-effect-microgravity-has-in-the-bfr-on-manned-trip-to)
- [Will spacex launch in an inclined fashion while returning from mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30935/will-spacex-launch-in-an-inclined-fashion-while-returning-from-mars)
- [Can BFS land on the Moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30883/can-bfs-land-on-the-moon)
- [Zero gee rice cooker for BFR's trip around the Moon; how would that work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/21522/zero-gee-rice-cooker-for-bfrs-trip-around-the-moon-how-would-that-work)
- [Why Spacex Lunar Mission date postponed?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30749/why-spacex-lunar-mission-date-postponed)
- [How the new BFS is supposed to dock for refuelling?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30761/how-the-new-bfs-is-supposed-to-dock-for-refuelling)
- [Is SpaceX lunar mission only a flyby mission, or it is going to land on Moon too?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30698/is-spacex-lunar-mission-only-a-flyby-mission-or-it-is-going-to-land-on-moon-too)
- [Capacity of the BFR tanker -- how many flights to fully refuel the spaceship?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25155/capacity-of-the-bfr-tanker-how-many-flights-to-fully-refuel-the-spaceship)
- [SpaceX Lunar Mission when possibly will it take place in future?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27254/spacex-lunar-mission-when-possibly-will-it-take-place-in-future)
- [Silly concept: repurposing BFS into a spin-gravity habitat](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27144/silly-concept-repurposing-bfs-into-a-spin-gravity-habitat)
- [Can a spaceship land on an icy body using retropropulsion? wouldn't the ice melt?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27035/can-a-spaceship-land-on-an-icy-body-using-retropropulsion-wouldnt-the-ice-melt)
- [Why will the BFS reenter broadside rather than engine first?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/26585/why-will-the-bfs-reenter-broadside-rather-than-engine-first)
- [Would it be possible for SpaceX's BFR to return the Hubble Space Telescope to Earth in the future?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/26143/would-it-be-possible-for-spacexs-bfr-to-return-the-hubble-space-telescope-to-ea)
- [Range of BFR as single stage](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24096/range-of-bfr-as-single-stage)
- [What are the details of the SSTO Mars profile for the BFR?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25707/what-are-the-details-of-the-ssto-mars-profile-for-the-bfr)
- [What will the heat shield on the BFS be made of](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25255/what-will-the-heat-shield-on-the-bfs-be-made-of)
- [Why 31 engines for the BFR?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25158/why-31-engines-for-the-bfr)
- [How will BFS maneuver during aerobraking?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24519/how-will-bfs-maneuver-during-aerobraking)
- [How long can it be reasonably expected to wait for the first flight of SpaceX's BFR?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23954/how-long-can-it-be-reasonably-expected-to-wait-for-the-first-flight-of-spacexs)
- [What kind of robots will be sent to Mars with the first BFR(s)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23648/what-kind-of-robots-will-be-sent-to-mars-with-the-first-bfrs)

[spacex-super-heavy](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacex-super-heavy):

- [Technology to directly observe an exoplanets](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25587/technology-to-directly-observe-an-exoplanets)
- [New BFR Engine arrangement](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30791/new-bfr-engine-arrangement)
- [Why is BFR replacing the Falcon 9?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25200/why-is-bfr-replacing-the-falcon-9)
- [How many SpaceX Starlink Internet-service satellites could be deployed in a single Falcon 9 launch? Falcon Heavy? BFR?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25525/how-many-spacex-starlink-internet-service-satellites-could-be-deployed-in-a-sing)
- [Will Falcon 9 block 5 successful launch speed up production of BFR?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27226/will-falcon-9-block-5-successful-launch-speed-up-production-of-bfr)
- [Will SpaceX use a BFR Heavy mode, similar to the Falcon Heavy but with 3 BFR cores?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25165/will-spacex-use-a-bfr-heavy-mode-similar-to-the-falcon-heavy-but-with-3-bfr-cor)

Both:

- [should spacex have 2 versions of the BFS (sub-orbital city and orbital BFR)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32970/should-spacex-have-2-versions-of-the-bfs-sub-orbital-city-and-orbital-bfr)
- [How much noise would the BFR make at launch?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32076/how-much-noise-would-the-bfr-make-at-launch)
- [Where will SpaceX build and launch the BFR?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25453/where-will-spacex-build-and-launch-the-bfr)
- [Why is SpaceX building the Big Falcon Ship before the Big Falcon Rocket?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25968/why-is-spacex-building-the-big-falcon-ship-before-the-big-falcon-rocket)
- [Is it viable to use one or more BFR tankers as interplanetary boosters](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25278/is-it-viable-to-use-one-or-more-bfr-tankers-as-interplanetary-boosters)

Comment: Retagging complete.